# Error System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Tags: visual-studio

I got a problem with a project I'm making
 it's program that gets signature from a wacom 
 sign pad It works fine at first run then whenever
 I try to enter another signature for the second 
 time it gets this error message

Here is the code:

```
   Dim sigCtl As New SigCtl
    Dim dc As New DynamicCapture
    Dim res As DynamicCaptureResult
    sigCtl.Licence = "AgAZAPZTkH0EBVdhY29tClNESyBTYW1wbGUBAoECA2UA"
    res = dc.Capture(sigCtl, "who", "why", vbNull, vbNull)
    If (res = DynamicCaptureResult.DynCaptOK) Then
        print("signature captured successfully")
        Dim sigObj As SigObj
        sigObj = sigCtl.Signature
        sigObj.ExtraData("AdditionalData") = "VB test: Additional data"
        Dim filename As New String("sig1.png")
```

sigObj.RenderBitmap(filename, 200, 150, "image/png", 0.5F, &HFF0000, &HFFFFFF,   -1.0F, -1.0F, _
            RBFlags.RenderOutputFilename Or RBFlags.RenderColor32BPP Or               RBFlags.RenderEncodeData)

```
        sigImage.Load(filename)
    Else
        print("Signature capture error res=" & res)
        Select Case res
            Case DynamicCaptureResult.DynCaptCancel
                print("signature cancelled")
            Case DynamicCaptureResult.DynCaptError
                print("no capture service available")
            Case DynamicCaptureResult.DynCaptPadError
                print("signing device error")
            Case Else
                print("Unexpected error code ")
        End Select
    End If
```

The error occurs around sigobj.rederbitmap  syntax it gives of the System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException exception

I'm kinda puzzled whats wrong here since it always work at first try

Thanks in advance**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a wacom STU-530 device.
What worked for me was to change the filename string each time the user wanted to use another test.

```
Dim rndm As New Random
Dim serial As Integer = rndm.Next(1, 9999)
Dim str_serial As String = CStr(serial)
Dim filename As New String("sig_" & str_serial.PadLeft(4, "0") & ".png")
```